# How to prevent fake mining in mining bitcoin?

Tags: mining-theory

After searching about how bitcoin miners mining bitcoin work I started to thinking bitcoin miners can cheat in mining bitcoin like they said they has solved the hash and verify it while they don't really solved the hash and verify it so how can it be prevent and anyone please explaining to me? Please?

Comment: can you be a bit more specific? Do you mean, a miner can send a solution to the nonce calculation, that isn't the solution? Maybe outline a bit ...

Answer (score 5):

A miner can't simply claim they solved the hash, because the result of the mining becomes part of the next block and *everybody else on the network* checks to see whether the calculation was done correctly.

If a miner tries to "fake" a block, the trickery would be immediately detected by every peer the miner sends it to, and the block would go nowhere.

Comment: What I mean is in verify

Comment: The network verifies/validates all blocks that are mined. If a block is not valid, a node will simply ignore and discard it. The verification is a cryptographic math function that cannot be faked. In extremely over-simplified terms, it’s like if a miner made a block that claimed ‘2+2=5’. Everyone else in the network would easily be able to figure out that the math doesn’t check out, and know the block is invalid.

Comment: If a block is not completely valid, it is completely ignored. Effectively, it is considered to be just some random junk.